# Capture gcloud composer run response in variable and test run

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm currently building a pipeline for airflow via GCP, and I'm currently experiencing two road blocks.

1. I would like to capture `gcloud composer run` responses. For example, if I run 
   `gcloud composer environments run some_environment\
   --location us-west2 \
   list_dags -- -sd /home/airflow/gcs/data/test`
   the results show the dags in that folder. However, there's no way to capture those values in a variable(s). I've tried using the `$()` and backticks, but when I `echo`, it's empty.
2. I would like to run the dag in the `/home/airflow/gcs/data/test` folder instead of `home/airflow/gcs/dags`. The command I attempted was `gcloud composer environments run some_environment --location us-west2 trigger_dag -- -sd /home/airflow/gcs/data/test example_dag`, but it still attempts to find the dag in `/home/airflow/gcs/dags`

Any help would be awesome! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the answer to the first question (regarding output). `gcloud composer` outputs to `stderr` not `stdout`. To echo the response, the command would be 
`gcloud composer environments run some_environment \
--location us-west2 \
list_dags -- -sd /home/airflow/gcs/data/test 2>&1`

***Still haven't figured out the answer to the 2nd question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on your Airflow Configuration file. From the Airflow Web UI, click on Admin->Configuration and find the value of "dags_folder" (must be set to /home/airflow/gcs/dags). Maybe you can update it using the [update command](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/environment-variables) if it's not [blocked](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/airflow-configurations)